# Django many-to-many self field and str() method of model

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, many-to-many

Good day!

I have quite simple model with many-to-one or many-to-many 'self' fields like `land_plot_prev_id`:

```
class LAND_PLOT(models.Model):
    land_plot_id = models.AutoField (primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)             
    land_plot_prev_id = models.ManyToManyField ('self', through = 'LT_LANDPLOT_FROM_LANDPLOT', symmetrical = False, related_name='lt_land_plot_id_previous', blank=True, null=True)
    # ...
    def __str__(self):
        return(str(self.land_plot_id) + "  (" + self.district_id.district_name + " " + str(self.land_plot_endorsed_square) + " m.)")
```

And in my template I use fields like `land_plot_prev_id` to show html `<select>` or `<select multiple>` by this way:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0">
    <div class="input-group multiply-full">
        <span class="input-group-addon" title="...">ZU№</span>
            {{form.land_plot_prev_id}}  
    </div>
</div>
```

And I've found recently very strange things in hitting DB by django:

1. In all cases of `forms.ModelChoiceField` or `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` django hit DB by (which are use .str() metods of models) `select * from ...`
2. In all cases `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField` django hit DB by `select * from ...` and by `select land_plot_prev_id from ...` for each land_plot_prev_id in DB!
3. Every time I use {{form.*foreign_key_name*}} django hit DB `select * from ...` and only afte that take value *foreign_key_name*

If I have *formsets* with html fields which are created by ModelChoiceField 
the number of such `select * from ...` is multiplied on the number of forms in given formset.

I'he came to conclusion that I should avoid using tags `{{ form.foreign_key }}` at all.

PS
I use Django Debug Toolbar for checking SQl generated by django ORM